# pip устанавливает сам себя?

Tags: python, pip

Почему `pip` находится в PyPI, ведь его нельзя установить без `pip`? Для установки указана команда `pip install pip` - https://pypi.org/project/pip/.

Comment: Где именно такое написано? Даже обновляется он не через себя, а через питон: `python -m pip install --upgrade pip`

Comment: @CrazyElf прям под названием пакета по ссылке

Comment: Это автоматическая ссылка, которая формируется по имени модуля/пакета.

Comment: @udmurt Слона то я и не приметил ))  Прикольно

Comment: @Эникейщик то есть большими буквами на официальной странице показана неверная команда?

Comment: @udmurt Ну, насколько я помню, если не получится её выполнить, она напишет, какую команду нужно использовать (через питон устанавливать, да)

Comment: То есть да. Вы такой ответ хотите? 

Comment: @Эникейщик надо репортить баг

Comment: @udmurt Думаю, это не баг, это прикол. В питоне бывает.

Answer (score 1):

часто это просто модуль для обновления pip.

```console
pip install --upgrade pip
```

Answer (score 0):

Согласно [официальной документации](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installation/), первичная установка `pip` выполняется одним из двух способов:

- Вызовом пакета `ensurepip`, входящего в стандартную поставку python:

  ```
   python -m ensurepip --upgrade
  ```
- Скачиванием и запуском [get-pip.py](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py)

Т.е. вопреки вашим словам, на самом деле для установки `pip` не нужно иметь уже установленный `pip`.

Сам pip не входит в комплект python, так как он вызывает проблемы при совместном использовании с другими популярными менеджерами пакетов python, такими как Conda и Poetry.